# Project Management textbook

Tags: books

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Project Management book that left the most impact on you?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/19/what-is-the-project-management-book-that-left-the-most-impact-on-you)

What would be a good text book for Project Management?

I want to read about your recommendations for a great Project Management text book.  I also would like to know why so.

Comment: Maybe a dup of http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/19/430 ?